# Does AWS Resources have common attributes like Network devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, resources

Network devices like Switch / Routers follow some standards and have basic common attributes, All devices having System MIB implementation, we can at least get what is the Serial Number, IOS version, Model, etc., Similarly, AWS Cloud Network resources like VPC, Subnet, IGW, TGW are having common attribute like resource id, name, type, etc.,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Say for example I am writing a small application that just shows me all the cloud resources I created in the cloud.

I need to collect the Inventories of my resources but I don't want to write too much code to collect each resource and am also not interested in detailed information about my resource. All I want to know name, id, what is the type of resource either ec2 instance, lb, firewall, etc.,